# how to identify a font as symbolic in java?

Tags: java, fonts, symbols

I'm currently looking for a possibility in Java to identify a font as symbolic like OpenOffice does.
Characters with the font Windings or Webdings and so on should be rendered with the correct "pictures".

Anyone an idea how to distinguish between normal fonts and fonts with symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug [Java doesn't display all characters in the windows symbol font](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4549043) gives a clue regarding a characteristic which is unique to symbol fonts.

They are part of [SYMBOL_CHARSET](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/fontprop.html) (a WindowsCharsetName of a font.properties file)

So the [jdk1.6.0_10]\jre\lib\fontconfig.98.properties.src could be a first source of information to establish if a name of a font matches a symbol font, and should be loaded through [Property.load()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `SYMBOL_CHARSET` in my font properties file per VonC's answer.

A simple test seems to be [`if( !java.awt.Font#canDisplay('a') )`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28char%29). On my Windows box I get a list of symbol fonts including the mundane Symbol and Wingdings, and exotic ones like "Estrangelo Edessa".